# JIRA query language limit columns returned

Tags: jira, jql

If I have a JIRA instance with 25 columns and I only want to pull in 10 of those columns, how do I do that? I have not been able to find a command to include or exclude columns in the search.

Answer (score 2):

You can select specific columns/fields using JIRA Command Line Interface. Here is an example:

jira --action getIssueList --search "project = P1 AND status = Resolved"  --outputFormat=200 --columns "key, Summary"

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming by columns you mean fields for a JIRA issue and this is all taking place on the Search page of JIRA.

What you can do is click `Tools` and `Configure Columns` in the upper right section of the window that can allow you to:

- Add
- Remove
- Reposition

Any of the columns that represent each field value.